# WinDBG - !vad, what's the meaning of the column "Start" and "End"

Tags: memory, virtual, windbg

I have been using WinDBG latetly and I found this usefull !vad extension.
I am converting virtual to physical addresses.

Anyway, I didn't understand the meaning of the column "Start" and "End", what does it mean ?

If anyone is able to explain to me, that would be awesome. I can't find anything speaking about that on other websites, it might be too obvious...

Here is an exemple of the output :

`kd> !vad 824bc2f8
VAD     level      start      end    commit
82741bf8 ( 1)      78000    78045         8 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
824ef368 ( 2)      7f6f0    7f7ef         0 Mapped       EXECUTE_READ
824bc2f8 ( 0)      7ffb0    7ffd3         0 Mapped       READONLY
8273e508 ( 2)      7ffde    7ffde         1 Private      EXECUTE_READWRITE
82643fc8 ( 1)      7ffdf    7ffdf         1 Private      EXECUTE_READWRITE`

Extracted from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-vad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAD = virtual Address Descriptor

Vpn = Virtual Page Number

Page Size = 0x1000 normally (use GetSystemInformation() API )

0x01<sup>st</sup>  Page starts at 0x00 and ends at 0x1000 **( 1 * 0x1000 )**

0x10<sup>th</sup> Page starts at 0x10 and ends at 0x10000  **(0x10 * 0x1000)**
and so on until 0xffffffff the maximum for a 32 bit process address space

here is an explanation

look for an user mode process

```
kd> !process 0 0 explorer.exe
PROCESS 853bbd40  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0754    Peb: 7ffd5000  ParentCid: 072c
    DirBase: 17632000  ObjectTable: 8a0fda28  HandleCount: 687.
    Image: explorer.exe
```

set process context  _EPROCESS address in the results above

```
kd> .process /p /r /P /i 853bbd40
You need to continue execution (press 'g' <enter>) for the context
to be switched. When the debugger breaks in again, you will be in
the new process context.

kd> g    

Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction:
82897d00 cc              int     3
```

check if cr3 matches Directory Base  so that we are looking at the 
virtual address in proper context

```
kd> r cr3
cr3=17632000

kd> !process @$proc 1
PROCESS 853bbd40  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0754    Peb: 7ffd5000  ParentCid: 072c
    DirBase: 17632000  ObjectTable: 8a0fda28  HandleCount: 687.
    Image: explorer.exe
    VadRoot 8497e218 Vads 337 Clone 0 Private 2275. Modified 19. Locked 0.
```

check vad using the Vadroot from results above
for the main module name  and you can notice the start

```
kd> .shell -ci "!vad  8497e218" grep -i explorer.exe
85416348  2       c10       e90      4 Mapped  Exe  EXECUTE_WRITECOPY  \Windows\explorer.exe
```

check the peb for main module to see it corresponds to the **!vad->start  * PageSize**

```
kd> .shell -ci "!peb " grep -i c10000.*explorer.exe

          c10000 4ce796f3 Nov 20 15:07:55 2010 C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
```

see the end matches corresponds to the **!vad->End * pageSize**

```
kd> lma 0xc10000 

start    end        module name
00c10000 00e91000   Explorer   (pdb symbols)          

e:\symbols\explorer.pdb\57A762C063044F9C81BC4B8895FBF1AB2\explorer.pdb
```